# Only 1 option in mod menu works (could not read memory error)

Tags: python, memory

The ammo function works when run, but godmode returns:

```
  File "C:\Users\miko\OneDrive\Desktop\other.py", line 54, in GetPtrAddr
    addr = pm.read_int(addr + i)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\miko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymem\__init__.py", line 658, in read_int
    raise pymem.exception.MemoryReadError(address, struct.calcsize('i'), e.error_code)
pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: 48, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
```

```
import os
import time
from colorama import Fore
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *


pm = pymem.Pymem("ac_client.exe")
gameModule = module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "ac_client.exe").lpBaseOfDll

status_ammo = "OFF"
status_godmode = "OFF"

def func_ammo():
    ammo_offsets = [0x8, 0x250, 0x98, 0x7AC]
    pm.write_int(GetPtrAddr(gameModule + 0x00183828, ammo_offsets), 1337)
    status_ammo = "ON"
    menu()

def func_godmode():
    godmode_offsets = [0xBBC, 0x30, 0x64, 0x98, 0x9C, 0xC0, 0x8]
    pm.write_int(GetPtrAddr(gameModule + 0x00183828, godmode_offsets), 1500)
    status_godmode = "ON"
    menu()

def menu():
    os.system('cls')
    print("1 - Unlimited Ammo [", status_ammo, "]")
    print("2 - God Mode [", status_godmode, "]\n")
    opt = input("Enter: ")
    if opt == "1":
        print("starting ammo")
        func_ammo()
    elif  opt == "2":
        print("starting godmode")
        func_godmode()
    else:
        print("\nInvalid Option")
        time.sleep(4)
        os.system('cls')
        menu()


def GetPtrAddr(base, offsets):
    addr = pm.read_int(base)
    for i in offsets:
        if i != offsets[-1]:
            addr = pm.read_int(addr + i)
    return addr + offsets[-1]

menu()
```

How can I fix this error?